# Not able to create SimpleName for '.class' string pattern

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Having a problem with the ast.newSimpleName() method.

I am not able to create a SimpleName of the sort 'SomeJava.class'. But the method works fine for names like 'SWT.None' or 'SomeJava.None'.

Here is the code :

```
MethodInvocation loggerInstance = ast.newMethodInvocation();

loggerInstance.setExpression(ast.newSimpleName("Logger"));
loggerInstance.setName(ast.newSimpleName("getLogger"));

String[] name1 = {className.replace(".java", ""),"None"};
String[] name2 = {className.replace(".java", ""), "class"};

loggerInstance.arguments().add(ast.newName(name1)); // This works
loggerInstance.arguments().add(ast.newName(name2)); // This doesn't
```

Should i use any thing else other than SimpleName for this. Thanks in advance.

---

***Edit*** : This is the statement i want to construct:

```
    Logger.getLogger(ClientTest.class);
```

During my analysis, i found out that the problem arises when using the "class" literal. Not sure how to overcome this.

```
    ast.newName("class");
    ast.newSimpleName("class");
```

Comment: class is not allowed as a name it's a resevered key word. Thus the behavior makes sense. To get a more specific answer you should add the tool your using to create the ast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from ASTView. Finally downloaded and installed it. :)

It should be a generated as a TypeLiteral, not as a SimpleName/Name.

```
TypeLiteral typeLiteral = ast.newTypeLiteral();
typeLiteral.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName(className)));
```

Comment: Great! I hope that you will not need to ask such questions anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use ASTView plugin (http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) to see what is the type of node for 'ClientTest.class' and then construct that type of node.